# Accessing related data in if statment inside foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables. Vlans, IPNets and Equipments

Vlans has a one to many relationship with IPNets, and Equipmentshas a one to many relationship with IPNets.

in my details view for Vlans I have this foreach.

```
                    @foreach (var item in Model.IPNets)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipment.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IPAddresse)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipment.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipment.EquipmentTypes.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipment.Departments.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipment.Location)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          @if (item.Equipment.PacsId == 1)
                            {
                            <small class="label bg-green">PACS</small>
                            }
                }
```

The modelitems are working fine and generates a table with alle items in IPNets matching the relationship with Vlans.

The problem is the if statement. As it is now I get "object is not set to an instance of an object".

using item.EquipmentId which is the foreign key in IPNets is working but is not the property I want to use.

Using @if (modelItem => item.Equipment.PacsId == 1) gives error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

**ViewModel**

```
    public class VlansViewModel
{
    public int VlanId { get; set; }

    public string Zone { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public string VlanName { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }

    public string IPNet { get; set; }

    public string IPStart { get; set; }

    public string IPEnd { get; set; }

    public string Mask { get; set; }

    public string Gateway { get; set; }

    public Location? Location { get; set; }

    public string Cidr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IPNet> IPNets { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }



    public VlansViewModel(Vlan vlan)
      {
         VlanId = vlan.VlanId;
         Zone = vlan.Zone;
         Number = vlan.Number;
         VlanName = vlan.Name;
         Info = vlan.Info;
         IPNet = vlan.IPNet;
         IPStart = vlan.IPStart;
         IPEnd = vlan.IPEnd;
         Mask = vlan.Mask;
         Gateway = vlan.Gateway;
         Cidr = vlan.Cidr;
         IPNets = vlan.IPNets;
         Location = vlan.Location;
    }


}
```

**Controller**

```
        // GET: Vlans/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        // Get current Id
        var vlansid = db.Vlans.Find(id);

        //ViewModel
        var ViewModel = new VlansViewModel(vlansid);

        return View("Details", ViewModel);
    }
```

Any suggestions how i can use item.Equipment.PacsId in my if statement?

### Update

As Shyju pointed out, the Equipment property is indeed null when the if statement is included. But I just dont understand how to include the property when Vlans don't have a relation with it.

I guess I would need to have a query in the controller which includes Equipments where EquipmentId equals IPNets.EquipmentId, but I have been trying to figure this out for so long now that everything is starting to merge into one big blur.

And I also don't understand why modelItem => item.Equipment.PacsId is loading the right values but item.Equipment.PacsId is giving null. I'm new to this and would appreciate if anyone could give an short explanation.

Comment: Make sure you have the `Equipment` property loaded(so it is not `null`). You might need to use the `Include` method.

Comment: @Shyju How do I include the `Equipment` property when there's no direct relation between `Vlans` and `Equipment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for null, and continue if not null:

```
@if (item.Equipment != null && item.Equipment.PacsId == 1)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Important to check to see if an object is `null` first before accessing a property/method on it (unless you're *sure* that it won't be null).